# How to line up columns of a pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that is being created like this:

```
date    Services Uptime     Services Downtime   Centers Downtime Centers Uptime
-----   --------- -     ------------------    ----------------    ---------------
12/5/14      100.00%              0.00%                   100.00%        100.00%    
12/12/14     100.00%              0.00%                     0.00%          0.00%
12/19/14     100.00%              0.00%                   100.00%        0.00%
12/26/14     100.00%              0.00%                   100.00%         0.00%
```

I would like it to come out as a pivot table, like this:

```
Date         Name                Uptime               Downtime
-----        ------            ---------            -------------
12/5/14     Services             100.00%                 0.00%  
12/5/14      Center              100.00%               100.00%
12/12/14    services             100.00%                 0.00%  
12/12/14    Center                 0.00%                 0.00%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need to `unpivot` instead of pivoting. I will do this using `cross apply` with `tables valued constructor`.

Performance wise this will be better than `Union All` if you have some more `names`

```
SELECT [date],NAME, uptime, downtime
FROM   Yourtable
       CROSS apply (VALUES ('service',Services_Uptime,Services_Downtime),
                           ('center',Centers_Uptime,Centers_Downtime) ) 
                    cs (NAME, uptime, downtime)
```

Comment: Thanks for your better answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have those 2 values, try a UNION:

```
select  [date]
        ,'Services'
        ,[Services Uptime] as Uptime
        ,[Services Dowtime] as Downtime
from    myTable
union all
select  [date]
        ,'Center'
        ,[Centers Uptime] as Uptime
        ,[Centers Dowtime] as Downtime
from    myTable
```

*Edited: to include Jason suggestion about "union **all**"*

Comment: While this isn't wrong, using `union all` instead of `union` can (depending on tables, indexes, etc) drastically improve performance in situations like this (where you won't have any duplicate rows, anyways).

Comment: Thanks Man, but i have more than 6 values like that. could you pls. suggest  me a best way.